# How to restrict some users to login in application using jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I want to create a script such that where I want to restrict some users to enter into application.

Means in my csv data set configuration, there comprises a lots of number of users. So instead of deleting that users from data set config, I want to restrict that users to login in application.

While executing that JMeter script, when one of the unwanted user is come to login on server, that time JMeter should restrict that users and moved forward on next user.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter cannot "restrict" the user from logging in. If there is some flag in the CSV file like specific username or list of "unwanted" username or a special column which indicates whether user should be logged in or not - you can use [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) and just don't execute the login if the user is "restricted"

Alternative option is using [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) and set the sampler as successful when it fails due to "restricted" credentials.